# Is it allowed to re-submit an edit?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I edited this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209481/is-my-device-hacked). It was rightly rejected because of a subsequent edit. After seen the (subsequent) edit, I then made a new one.

I then started to think. Am I allowed to do that (re-submit my edit)?

I tried to check, but I have not seen a former question related to the issue. If there is one please, let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's rejected by the system to avoid conflict, which doesn't imply that your edit was bad in any way.

So if you feel your suggestion is good, you're always encouraged to suggest it again. People with the "review suggested edits" privilege (at 2,000 reputation) will be happy to review and approve it.